# How to return the number of values input into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, static

At the moment, I am stumped and cannot progress on this problem. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. The first part is working, however when I try to return the # of user inputs in the second part I get a Segmentation Fault. Below are the descriptions of both parts::

P2.1    Write a program consisting of main and displayArray functions. The main function declares an integer array with 10 elements and at the same time initializes them with up to 10 arbitrary values. The main function then calls displayArray function to display the contents of the array.

P2.2    Expand P2.1 with an additional fillArray function that prompts the user to enter up to 10 (size of the array) integers.  Since a statically allocated array is often partially filled with values less than the actual size or storage capacity of the array (10 in our case), so the fillArray function must return a positive integer value representing the actual # of input values entered by the user.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int displayArray(int arr[]);
int fillArray(int newArray[], int &inputs);

const int size = 10;

int main() {

    int x, inputs = 0;
    int arr[size] = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    int newArray[] = {};

    displayArray(arr);

    cout << "Enter .5 when finished. ";
    fillArray(newArray, inputs);

    cout << inputs;

    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}

int displayArray(int arr[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " " << endl;

}

int fillArray(int newArray[], int &inputs) {

    for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
        cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
        cin >> newArray[i];

        if(newArray[i] == .5) {
            inputs = i + 1;
            return inputs;
            break;
        }           
    } 

}
```

Comment: Arrays suck. `int newArray[] = { };` really sucks. It has a size of zero. You can't really do much of anything with it. There's probably a compiler warning about this in the build output.

Comment: `if(newArray[i] == .5)`never would evaluate to `true`

Comment: C++ usually prefers [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Are you restricted from using those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not reserve memory for your `newArray`, since `int newArray[] = {}` will allocate an array of size `0` (actually not even defined as far as I know). So when calling `fillArray`, you will exceed array bounds.

Write

```
int newArray[10] = { 0 }
```

and it should at least work if you do not enter more than `10` values then.

Further, in `fillArray`, to not run out of bounds, I'd write...

```
int fillArray(int newArray[], int &inputs) {

    for(inputs = 0; inputs < 10 ; inputs++) {
       cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
       cin >> newArray[i];

       if(newArray[i] == 0) {
         break;
       }
    }
    inputs++;
    return inputs;
}
```

Note further that the `newArray[i] == .5` is at least misleading, since `newArray` is of type `int` and `.5` is a floating point value. It will never evaluate to `true`, since the integral value `newArray[i]` will be converted to a `float` before comparison, and this conversion will never result in `0.5`.